# How to convert .xcf files to .png files in batch?

Tags: gimp

I'm using Windows. I have a folder with `.xcf` files, each `100x100px`. I would like to run a process that will convert them to `.png` files making them `40x40px`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might succeed using [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) which also [supports XCF for reading](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php). They also provide [Windows binaries](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows). The tool also has various [transformation (scaling) options](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/), so you can convert and scale each image with one call:

```
convert source.xcf -resize 40x40 target.png
```

I'm not fluent with Windows batch programming and don't have access to Windows PC right now, I think a simple loop would look something like this:

```
for %%f in (*.xcf) do (
    convert %%f -resize 40x40 %%~nf.png
)
```

Comment: I've tried using ImageMagick. I can't understand how to use it to achieve what I set out in this question. I can see that it's powerful but for a person that doesn't have a background in programming this answer is bad.

Comment: @SBel: a) This site is for developers, how could I guess that you aren't one? You haven't told. This tool does everything you need, it's free and you don't even need to compile it. b) What's bad about `convert source.xcf -resize 40x40 target.png`? c) Do you need the necessary batch loop as well? Or complete batch (`.bat`) file? Did you expect a ready-made GUI app?

Comment: @DarkDust, you might want to put that example in your answer also.